# Exportar datos de una consulta a CSV desde Phpmyadmin my

Tags: phpmyadmin

Necesito descargar informes de la base de datos de mi host la consulta me trae mas de 5000 datos pero a a la hora de exportar no trae todos los datos, por lo cual me toca filtrar y traer pocos datos y después unirlos para crear un informe ¿Existe una manera para descargar la información en CSV y que sea de manera completa?

Comment: Tendrías que averiguar por qué se trae menos datos. Te pregunta en algún momento cuántas filas traer? Te advierte que sólo traerá N filas? Cómo haces hoy para exportar los pedazos? Me imagino que limitas las filas a una cantidad menor y vas variando el offset. ¿Probaste descargando un archivo comprimido?

Comment: Segun investigue phpadmin tiene un limite de tamaño de archivo para exportar si supera ese tamaño te trae filas hasta que llegue a ese peso.

Answer (score 0):

Hay varias cosas que yo probaría. Hay que partir de la base que la exportación se interrumpe por agotamiento del tiempo máximo (time_limit) o por memoria.

Primero, ver si puedes descargar comprimiendo con zip o gzip:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Segundo, ve si aumentando el tiempo límite a un tiempo muy holgado cambia la cantidad de filas exportadas. En `config.inc.php` añade:

```
$cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 3600;
```

No creo que la exportación dure una hora...

Tercero, aumenta el límite de memoria. También en `config.inc.php`:

```
$cfg['MemoryLimit'] = '512M';
```

Cuarto, intenta guardar el archivo localmente del lado del servidor en vez de enviarlo a tu browser. En el mismo `config.inc.php`:

```
$cfg['SaveDir'] = __DIR__;
```

Eso guardará el CSV en la raíz de tu instalación de PHPMyAdmin.